# Why is pointer arithmetic the cause of a segfault?

Tags: rust

Why is this pointer arithmetic (without reading or writing data behind these pointers) the cause of a segfault?

```
#![allow(dead_code,unused_variables)]
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Bar<T: ?Sized> {
    a: Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}

unsafe fn foo<T: ?Sized>(v: &T) {
    let fake: &Bar<T> = std::mem::zeroed();

    // segfault on this line
    // we are not reading or writing uninitialized data behind the reference, 
    // but only doing pointer arithmetic. We are not reading or writing 
    // uninitialized vtable, but only copy the vtable pointer.
    let fake_val = &fake.value;
}


fn main() {
    use std::any::Any;

    let some_ref: &Any = &42 as &Any;
    unsafe { foo(some_ref) };
}
```

([On Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=61e79fc78c62b286f27d869060965b4a&version=nightly))

Output: `Segmentation fault`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Rust, [**merely creating a dangling reference is undefined behavior**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html)! This allows the compiler to perform some aggressive optimizations around references, that wouldn't be possible otherwise.

In this particular case, the compiler generates [code which calculates the offset for the field by using the `align` value in the vtable](https://godbolt.org/g/EChH1g). So it tries to dereference the vptr which causes the segfault.

---

To have dangling pointer, you shouldn't use a *reference*, but a [*raw pointer*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html). You can have dangling raw pointers without a problem!

```
let fake: *const Bar<T> = std::ptr::null();
```

Comment: If it's safe to have a dangling pointer with a raw pointer, why does this exhibit the same behavior as the OP's code (e.g fails in Debug, "works" in Release)
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=23baa08f2c83609e002f33b3e2852543&version=stable

Comment: @Timidger Because you dereference the pointer in that second line. Dereferencing a dangling pointer is, of course, not allowed. So you can't get the pointer to the field with the `.` operator. To be honest, I don't know what the best way to obtain such a pointer to a field is. Better ask another question! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing a null pointer on the line you indicated. You are correct that you are taking a reference to that value, but the code that rustc outputs for LLVM is very stupid in debug mode. Try running this in release mode, and you'll see that *probably* the optimizer will be kind to you and this will no longer segfault.

Since this is UB, please don't depend on this for real code.

Comment: Arguably, if the the program compiled in debug mode segfaults in case of undefined behaviour, that makes it certainly not that stupid. :P In Rust, obtaining a reference to invalid content is just as illegal as directly accessing that content, so a segfault is one of the "best" consequences we could wish for.